# Finding notes sounding at the same time in a different voice in a midi file

Tags: python, midi, music21

I have a midi file consisting of two parts. Now I need to print out, for each note in part 0 (including rests), which note sounds at the same time in part 1 (and the note that proceeds this).

I can go through all of the notes in part 0 with music21, but how do I find the note at that time in part 1. Will I need to use end times? Or is there a function for this?

```
for thisNote in s.parts[0].notes:
    print thisNote.ps
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very interesting function that let me solve this:

```
secondPart = s.parts[1]

for thisNote in s.parts[0].notes:


   sys.stdout.write('at ' + str(thisNote.offset) + ' toppitch: ' + str(thisNote.ps))  

   soundingNotes = secondPart.getElementsByOffset(thisNote.offset,  mustFinishInSpan=False, mustBeginInSpan=False)


   try:
     if soundingNotes > 0:
       basslength = len(soundingNotes)

   except: 
     basslength = 0

   if basslength > 1:
     print "oh ow, more then one note sounding in the bass."

   if basslength > 0:
     if soundingNotes[0].isRest:
       sys.stdout.write(' bottompitch: R')
     else:
       sys.stdout.write(' bottompitch: ' + str(soundingNotes[0].ps)) # + ' from ' + str(soundingNotes[0].offset))

     # print the previous note

     soundingNotes2 = secondPart.getElementsByOffset(thisNote.offset-1,  mustFinishInSpan=False, mustBeginInSpan=False)
```